# Go back in a specific panorama/pivot item?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, pivot, back-button, panorama-control

I would like to know if is it possible when a user press "back button" to go in a specific pivot or panorama item on WP7 sdk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically set selected Panorama item in WP7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4622214/50447)

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure that the user is always returned to the item they left by overriding the `OnNavigatedFrom` and `OnNavigatedTo` events and using the `PhonePageApplication.State` property to store the selected item.  This will work even if the app is tombstoned while on a different page.

Something like:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    State.Add("selectedPivot", myPivot.SelectedIndex);

    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}



protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    myPivot.SelectedIndex = (int)State["selectedPivot"];

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Please note the above is untested, requires additonal checks and error handling, etc. but should be enough to get you started.

Comment: @RowlandShaw This works for Pivot (as in the sample). You can set DefaultIndex for the pano but this has side effects.

Answer (score 0):

It would be *possible* to implement this approach by implementing the `OnBackKeyPress` override in your page, however, this would not be consistent with back button behavior in Windows Phone 7 applications. The back button is supposed to only be used for navigating backwards through the application's page stack, and then to leave the application to navigate backwards through the application stack. To implement any other behavior would be counter-intuitive and is also highly likely to fail certification.

Comment: hello derek, i know how to override the onBackKeypress but its not intuitive when i.e in PivotItem3 user go in a menu then he press back button and he comes back in the PivotItem1 (default one). i hope u have understand me

Comment: The Back button should **only** be used for navigating backwards through the page stack and to cancel things like context menus, message boxes, etc. Perhaps you could update your question with some more detail about what you are trying to achieve and what's not working if my answer is not yet satisfactory.

Comment: well i have set a pivot in my app with 4 item : first one is the News, second is the pics, third the links and four the credits. if the user go in the "links part" and then he press the back button he would go back in the  "news" part which is not logic. i would like in this case when the user press back button, he goes in front of the "link" item. ty for ur patience

Comment: OK, so this is not what the back button is for. The user must use the standard flick gestures left and right to switch between items in the `Pivot` control. As stated in my original answer, to implement this by using the back button would be counter-intuitive for users and would almost certainly fail certification.

Comment: well i have upload a pic for better understanding (i m not that fluent in english)  http://hpics.li/fc95676. so my problem is : the user is in the pivot item 4, he goes into the menu where there is a lot of page he press back once, he goes at the menu start then i would like if he press again, he is redirected directly on the item pivot 4 and NOT in the item pivot 1. ty

Comment: Assuming that the user is performing a forwards navigation, and then pressing the back button to return to the original page, then this interaction is fine, and the solution that Matt has provided to persist/restore the selected item is the correct approach to take, though I'm surprised that it returns to the first item, and not the one they were on already.