# Programmatically slide to next Panorama item

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to programmatically move from one panorama page/item to the next **and get the same kind of animated sliding effect** you get when sliding with a finger?

I can use the PanoramaControl.DefaultItem property to move to the expected item/page, but you won't get the animated sliding effect. Any ideas here?

Comment: Not really, this is about the animation, not how to change item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not programatically possible to change the selected index of a panorama control. As you mention the only way of setting the index is using the DefaultItem property which is only useful when navigationg to the page which contains the panorama.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622214/how-to-programatically-set-selected-panorama-item-in-wp7) is another post that discusses it.

Answer (score 13):

Its possible, just put the setting of the DefaultItem between a SlideTransition Completed event and you are done:

```
public static class PanoramaExtensions
{
    public static void SlideToPage(this Panorama self, int item)
    {

        var slide_transition = new SlideTransition() { };
        slide_transition.Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideLeftFadeIn;
        ITransition transition = slide_transition.GetTransition(self);
        transition.Completed += delegate
        {
            self.DefaultItem = self.Items[item];
            transition.Stop();
        };
        transition.Begin();
    }
}
```

Use my_panorama.SlideToPage(1) to slide to the second page.

Comment: You should note, that your answer is based on the (non-standard) library Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit from CodePlex. Also, your code did depend on other fields in your class. I changed that so that the snipped is selfcontained. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

You can use below code :

```
panoramaRoot.DefaultItem = (PanoramaItem)panoramaRoot.Items[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be to create separate visual states for each item and create animated slide transitions for transitioning to each state. Then you can use `VisualStateManager.GoToState(<page>, <state>, true);` to initiate the state change.

Comment: I would not call this _the easiest way_ ;)

Comment: Maybe not the _easiest_, but the **only** way I could think of, making it easiest by default :P

Answer (score 1):

No - the panorama control doesn't support programmatic manipulation like this.

If you want an experience like this, then you could try a hand-written panorama control - e.g. http://phone.codeplex.com/