# How to navigate between panorama pages in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created a panorama app for wp7. I just want to navigate between the panorama pages. Like I have created some images and if i tapped any image, then it should be navigated to the third header or fourth header page. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Already asked questions which can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622214/how-to-programatically-set-selected-panorama-item-in-wp7

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350242/programatically-slide-to-next-panorama-item

Answer (score -2):

Let's say that your Panorama control has attribute x:Name="myPanorama".

Now to navigate beetwen PanoramaItem you have to set "SelectedIndxex" attribute:

```
myPanorama.SelectedIndex = 4;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work. The setter for SelectedIndex is private and therefore cannot be set by on the page it lives.