# Panorama navigation in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, panorama-control

It's very quick question but I was looking for it in Google for 2 days without any result...

How to navigate between screens in panorama? There is only one page so I guess that doesn't work:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Otherwise: How to change the place in panorama that will be displayed on the phone display?
Or how to change the panoramaItem that will be displayed?

Comment: that doesn't work in WP 7.8 though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PANORAMA_CONTROL.DefaultItem = PANORAMA_CONTROL.Items[1];
It will cause items to be a bit re-arranged since you are setting an item to be the first in the list, but other than that it is an acceptable way to do this, since it will actually bring the item in front of the user.

Comment: oh yeap, I found what was wrong... so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622214/how-to-programatically-set-selected-panorama-item-in-wp7  is workin :)