# How to Navigate to Panorama Item in Code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I would like to programmatically navigate to a specific panorama item based upon a click event. I tried doing something like the following

```
if (Panorama != null && Panorama.SelectedIndex != 3)
        {
            Panorama.SelectedIndex = 3;  //Error, SelectedIndex is read only
        }
```

but the `SelectedIndex` property cannot be set. Is there a way to do this in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622214/how-to-programatically-set-selected-panorama-item-in-wp7) It's for Windows Phone 7, but I think the same still applies to 8. Maybe you should consider a different navigation model for your app? Or changing the DefaultItem and refreshing the page (I wouldn't recommend this though, it would just look confusing)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it would work:

```
if (Panorama != null && Panorama.SelectedIndex != 3)
        {
            MyPanorama.DefaultItem = MyPanorama.Items[3];
        }
```

Comment: Question, if I set the default item here, then when the Page is NavigatedTo again will this now be the first Panorama item that is always shown? I have a button in my first panorama item, and when the user clicks it the 3rd panorama item should be scrolled to. (I should have put index=2 above).

Comment: you could set index of panorama according to your need